# Which date should I print as submission date on the title of my thesis when I send it by post to the deanery?

Tags: thesis, paper-submission, titles

Tomorrow I will print my thesis. On the title page, I have to write

Submitted on: xx.xx.xxxx

Typically, that is not an issue if you go to the deanery by foot and submit the thesis. However, I will send it via post and I do not know when the package with my thesis reach the deanery  exactly.

So, If I print it on 23.10.2023 and send it directly, I would use: submitted on: 27.10.2023

Or do I use the postal sent date? Is there a typical rule what is this date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The submission date is the date _on which you submitted it_, not the date _on which that submission was received_. So put the date you post it, as Bryan Krause recommended.

Comment: I think this one runs afoul of our "depends on individual factors" criterion personally. But it's a bit marginal because how could somebody who has this question know that? Might end up falling into exactly the class of examples that makes that close reason challenging to parse.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the date you send it by post, as that is the last date you have control of the submission.

If you are concerned, you could contact the office for further guidance.